# Error trying to run anchor test

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

trying to learn anchor dev, following soldev.app.
I have a problem, when I run anchor test, this is the error I get:

**Unable to get the latest blockhash. The test validator does not look started. Check .anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt for errors. Consider increasing [test.startup_wait] in Anchor.toml.**

**Ledger location: .anchor/test-ledger
Log: .anchor/test-ledger/validator.log
Initializing...
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at .anchor/test-ledger: blockstore error**

When I try to run `solana-test-validator` it works. In the anchor.toml file cluster is set to localnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `solana-test-validator` in a separate terminal.

Then run `anchor test --skip-local-validator` whenever you wanna test your program.

You can create an alias if this gets tedious. e.g. `alias anchortest="anchor test --skip-local-validator`

Comment: The flag `--skip-local-validator` is so badly named because you pass it to `anchor test` to skip local validator, and yet `anchor test` requires `solana-test-validator` to run (in a separate terminal). Sounds like a prank! HAHA.

Comment: I'm joining to @Nawaz There must be a self validator in test environment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the following to my `Anchor.toml` file, above `[scripts]`:

```
[test]
startup_wait = 20000
```